# Customize an individual Field symfony2.8

Tags: symfony, if-statement, twig

i have a variable rendered from from a controller to a twig file . i customized my form widget ..
the variable works well outside the block but in the block i have this error

Variable "date_seance" does not exist in CalendarBundle:Calendar:add_seance_candidate.html.twig at line 55

the line 55 is the if

```
                            {{ date_seance }} ( here it works well)
 <div class="form-group">
   {% form_theme form _self %}
      {% block _autoecole_calendarbundle_calendar_start_widget %}
          {% set type = type|default('text') %}
          <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if date_seance is not empty %} value="{{ date_seance }}" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" {% endif %} class="form-control" placeholder="Cliquer pour entrer la date du début..." />
      {% endblock %}


      {{ form_errors(form.start) }}
      ( here i display the widget start input text after customization )
      {{ form_widget(form.start) }}

 </div>
```

[this the tutorial in symfony cookbook .. How to Customize an individual Field](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form themes blocks have isolated scope, which means they do not inherit of parent variables, except if explicitly specified.

Here, you might want to replace `{{ form_widget(form.start) }}` by `{{ form_widget(form.start, {'date_seance' : date_seance}) }}` to explicitly pass your variable to your widget.

Comment: it works well thank you Sogara but i have 2 input start here why twig repeated it ?

Comment: No idea at all, can you edit your question with your whole Twig?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but maybe you should move your form theming in a separate template. It is possible that Twig renders the content of your `block _autoecole_calendarbundle_calendar_start_widget` independently of your `form_widget`.

Comment: what i have done before your comment just now hhhh i'm so thankful Sogara

Answer (score 0):

I can guess that date_seance variable is created inside a scope which means a tag like {% block %} {% nav %} {% for %} this variable can't be accessed from outside like this :

```
{% block A %}
    {% set var = 'apple' %}
    {{ var }} {# This prints apple #}
{% endblock %}

{% block B %}
    {{ var }} {# This doesn't prints anything, since var isn't defined #}
{% endblock %}
```

To make a variable accessible outside of their scope you need to define it before:

```
{% set var = 'apple' %}  

{% block A %}
    {{ var }} {# This prints apple #}
{% endblock %}
```

In your case try to define `date_seance` outside of any scope

Comment: i have done this before but doesn't work the solution in the answer of sogara but i have 2 input start here why twig repeated it ?